# One eye of model doesn't follow head?

Tags: objects, armature, rigging, weight-painting

**One eye of model doesn't follow head**?

I have a bit of a problem with a "4 Piece Model", "Head, Body, Eyes, Hair, and Teeth". I hope someone can be of assistance while the "Eye's" appear as a pair and don't act as a pair. Upon selecting the eyes in object mode they both highlight as a pair with a single click of one eye and then after shift selecting the models head and choosing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> > "BONE" the parent only applies to one eye and the left eye doesn't move with the head and rig movements? There is no lattice or such, or any such tracking.

Comment: Could you post a .blend file, it is hard to figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: I just put up the blend  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your eyes are incorrectly weight painted**. To fix this, Selected to vertex group *DEF-head* and go into edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Select all your vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and Hit Assign.

[image]